# Cambiar el texto de la barra de herramientas para que sea distinto al nombre de la aplicación

Tags: android-studio, material-design

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el texto de la toolbar de mi aplicación para que no sea igual que al nombre de la App? Algo así como el Traductor de Google.

Así figura al buscarlo (como Traductor):

[image: Se llama traductor]

Así aparece el nombre en la toolbar de la aplicacion (como "Google Traductor"):

[image: Aparece como "Google Traductor"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te refieres al titulo en la [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar), para cambiar este texto, puedes realizarlo de la siguiente forma, usando el método `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)`:

```
...//
        myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);

        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Mi titulo.");
//...
```